# Image Object in Advanced Custom Fields is not resizing properly

Tags: css, wordpress, image, advanced-custom-fields

We created a custom theme using ACF for Wordpress. Our issue is that we are resizing a single image 1440 x 320 to fit in 2 places. The first place which is working fine is Full post leadspace image which uses the full 1440 x 320 image. The issue we are having is for the Featured post view or Card layout the image needs to resize down to 380 w x 160 H. We are using Advanced Custom fields to add the image to the post. I will attach a photo of whats happening[image]

Comment: What does the loop that displays the images look like? You may be displaying the wrong image size.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem isn't ACF, but your add_image_size() function.
If you already defined the image size in your functions.php, it should look like this:

```
add_image_size ( "card", 380, 160, true );
```

The last argument (true), tells WordPress to crop the image. If this is set to false, the resized image will be 380px wide and the height will be proportionally. If you crop the image, WordPress will first resize the image, and then cut the image to 380x160px

Comment: // Heres the functions.php for our theme

update_option('thumbnail_crop', array(
    'right',
    'center'
));
add_image_size('size-380', 380, 380, array(
    'right',
    'center'
));
add_image_size('size-780', 780, 780, array(
    'right',
    'center'
));
add_image_size('size-1200', 1200, 1200, array(
    'right',
    'center'
));
add_image_size('size-1440', 1440, 1440, array(
    'right',
    'center'
));